# How To generate view for edmx to improve performance?

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, edmx

i have data layer,business layer and design layer,in which my .edmx file is placed in data layer.
now i want to generate views for my .edmx file to improve performance.
i tried the following process:
->set .edmx file's **Metadata Artiface Processing** property to "**Copy to Output Directory**" 
and then in my data layer's build event i put the following code:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" /nologo /language:CSharp
```

/mode:ViewGeneration "/inssdl:$(TargetDir)NeoSoftDataEntity.ssdl" 
"/incsdl:$(TargetDir)NeoSoftDataEntity.csdl" "/inmsl:$(TargetDir)NeoSoftDataEntity.msl" 
"/outviews:$(ProjectDir)NeoSoftDataEntity.Views.cs"
but when build the solution.
i get the following error:
****Error   2   The command ""%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" /nologo /language:CSharp 
/mode:ViewGeneration "/inssdl:D:\NeoSoftWinApp\NeoSoftWinApp\bin\Debug\NeoSoftDataEntity.ssdl" 
"/incsdl:D:\NeoSoftWinApp\NeoSoftWinApp\bin\Debug\NeoSoftDataEntity.csdl" "/inmsl:D:\NeoSoftWinApp\NeoSoftWinApp\bin\Debug\NeoSoftDataEntity.msl" 
"/outviews:D:\NeoSoftWinApp\NeoSoftWinApp\NeoSoftDataEntity.Views.cs"" exited with code 123.    NeoSoftWinApp***
*

how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are these paths D:\NeoSoftWinApp\NeoSoftWinApp\bin\Debug\NeoSoftDataEntity.ssdl correct? If the artifacts are not copied to the output directory but live in the project directory you may want to use "/incsdl:$(ProjectDir)NeoSoftDataEntity.csdl" instead of "/incsdl:$(TargetDir)NeoSoftDataEntity.csdl"

Answer (score 1):

If you copy/paste from the MSDN site, you need to remove the carriage return in your command.

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" /nologo /language:CSharp /mode:ViewGeneration "/inssdl:$(TargetDir)MyModel.ssdl" "/incsdl:$(TargetDir)MyModel.csdl" "/inmsl:$(TargetDir)MyModel.msl" "/outviews:$(ProjectDir)MyModel.Views.cs"
```